# Grid based decision making with Llama 2

Tags: huggingface, large-language-model, llama

I am new to the LLM and trying to build app with Llama 2 (7b), LangChain which can refer the grid and provide the decision. The grid is below as CSV file. I tried it through RAG but I am getting inconsistent output. Any suggestion for format change, structure change or different technique with some code guidance are well come.

```
"Age range in years" , "Annual Income range" ,"Segment code" , "Recommendation" 

"18 to 35","300000 to 750000","S1","2 Wheeler" 
"36 to 50","300000 to 750000","S2","2 Wheeler"
"18 to 35","750001 to 2500000","S3","Small Car" 
"36 to 50","750001 to 2500000","S4","Mid Range car" 
"51 to 58","750001 to 2500000","S5","SUV" 
"above 58", "above 2500001","S6","XUV" 
"above 58","750001 to 2500000","S7","Retired","SUV"
```